# Verify Error launching FlurryAgent

Tags: android, flurry

I have a problem with the `FlurryAgent.onStartSession()` method. It's returns a `java.lang.VerifyError` when I launch my app. This app is developed using **android 2.3** and I have a project added into it. This project contains the FlurryAgent.jar. When my app needs to run `FlurryAgent.onStartSession()` it returns a `VerifyError`.

I only have this problem when I launch it using a 1.6 device or emulator.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this problem. Thanks.

The main problem was that the FlurryAgent.jar was in the added project but not in the main project. In the 1.6 platform I can't to reference the FlurryAgent.jar methods if it wasn't into the main project.

Comment: Would you mind posting your solution in your answer so that others can benefit from it?

Comment: I have added my solution but I think that it isn't very useful.